# Match img tag based on url, with regex

Tags: regex, match

I have a string url of an image, and then I also have a html string of an article. Now, I need to find any img tags inside that html, that link to the image I have. So, not just the url, but the whole img tags, no matter how many other attributes it has.

My attempt was this, but it doesnt work as expected 
`<img.*?src="https://www.linktosomerandomimg.com/qwdoqwdqwd.png".*?/>)`

Comment: Why not just use a proper HTML parser? Using regular expressions to parse HTML is generally regarded as a fool's errand due to the extreme nuances/etc.

Comment: Please specify which type of regex you are using (for instance grep ERE, or PCRE). It would be best to show the actual command too, as there might be quoting issues. Also, please describe *what* isn't working as excepted. Give a sample input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Hi. Im using this in dart / flutter. I receive html string from backend, but not all images exist anymore in that hmtl, so the app crashes when it cant load one. So im fetching all the images via regex, sending a get req to them, to see if they exist, and if they dont, I remove them form the html. I simply use RegExp(). No idea what that uses (ere, pcre,...).